# Have Internet IP Emailed To You

Tags: ubuntu, ip, lubuntu

I use NoMachine Free for remote desktop, and my IP seems to change frequently. I don't always have time to check, so I want the IP to connect to to be mailed to me every day.

EDIT: This is not a network I own, and the owner doesn't want me to configure the router manually. Otherwise, I am free to do anything else. (it means not configuring Port Forwarding)
2nd EDIT: I will accept a program as a solution that will configure Port Forwarding itself (like NoMachine configuring the Gateway Port) 
EDIT: The IP SHOULD NOT be a 10.X.X.X or 192.168.X.X IP. These are in-network IPs and won't work when I'm away from home.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you are asking for, but have you looked into DDNS? If you are needing to connect to your machine from a remote location and due to standard ISP practice with residential customers (unless you pay for a static IP), DDNS may be your best option. Please try to reword your question to help us understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Putting `curl checkip.dyndns.org` in crontab should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is a standard Ubuntu box you can create a daily cron job to email you your IP address etc.

I'm not at my PC at the moment, so can't check this exactly, but you can add a line like the following to /etc/crontab:

01 01 * * *  root /sbin/ifconfig ethX | /bin/mail -s "new IP for machinename" user@email

That said, this is a solved problem - there are any number of dynamic DNS providers which you can hook your box into which will periodically update a domain name with the correct IP address.  (First one I googled was www.no-ip.com)

Comment: is this the private address or the one I can use to connect with you from outside my home network

Comment: In the case of the cron command it takes the IP address of the machine (you may be able to use curl or whether to get the external IP ). In the case of the dynamic DNS provider it will be the world reachable IP.

Comment: How does this work, exactly?

Comment: How does what work?  This is all (conceptually) straight forward. Have you tried Googling?

Comment: on the topic of no-ip, do I need to configure ports to use no-ip?